# Debug mode in chrome throws exception

Tags: javascript

I am getting

> (CONTENT_SCRIPT context for bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj)
>   messaging.dispatchOnConnect at h1.js in chrome is not a function

error in Chrome.

suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Impossible to say for sure with the complete lack of information that you've provided, but you appear to be calling a function that you haven't defined, or are trying to call a non-function.

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused by the [*"Honey"*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/honey/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj?hl=en-US) extension (if you [google for "bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj"](https://www.google.com/search?q=bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj&gws_rd=cr&fg=1) you'd find it).

You should contact its developer.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by uninstalling the "Honey" extension.